# ParallelStream and JPA returning empty content

Tags: java, jpa, parallel-processing

I have a unit test where I fill in my data with these

```
@DataJpaTest
@TestExecutionListeners({ TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class, DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class, MockitoTestExecutionListener.class })
@DatabaseSetup(value = "/dataset/myDataSet.xml", type = DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT)
@DatabaseTearDown(value = "/dataset/myDataSet.xml", type = DatabaseOperation.DELETE_ALL)
public class MyTest {
    private ClassToBeTested classToTest;
    
    @MockBean
    private MyObjRepository myObjRepo;
    @MockBean
    private MyRepository myRepo;
    
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        classToTest = new ClassToBeTested(myRepo);
    }
        
    @Test
    void myTest() {
        //we have 2 objects added in the DB
        classToTest.scheduleFixedDelayTask();
    }
}


public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<OtherObject, Long> {
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class ClassToBeTested {
    private final MyObjRepository myObjRepo;
    private final MyRepository myRepo;
    
    
    @Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${my.var}")
    public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
        manage();
    }

    protected void manage() {
        MyObj obj1 = myObjRepo.findByName("obj1");
        MyObj obj2 = myObjRepo.findByName("obj2");
        Map<String, List<MyObj>> myMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        myMap.put("obj1", Collections.singletonList(obj1));
        myMap.put("obj2", Collections.singletonList(obj2));
        myMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach(items -> {
            for (MyObj item : items.getValue()) {
                List<OtherObject> otherObjects = MyRepository.findAll();
                log.info("TEST: " + CollectionUtils.isEmpty(otherObjects));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I use parallelStream, I get the stacktrace

TEST: true

TEST: false

// Not correct, should be false / false

And when I use stream, I get the stacktrace

TEST: false

TEST: false

obj1 and obj2 are not null must I say

Do you know what could be wrong?

Thanks for your help

Julien

Comment: Don't know why my edit to add the hello does not work, but I wrote this somewhere else and I forgot it :)

Comment: You should test the Repository separately from your Service.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your response. I agree but that's not the problem I am trying to understand. I am trying to figure out what could make a parallelStream fail where a stream would not

Comment: My point is, that your setup, even for the point of "understanding why parelell streams behave differently" is not minimal. There is so much stuff going on here.

Comment: Maybe `shipmentSecurityActionRepository` (where does it even come from?) uses thread local variables or such alike. Not that I would expect much parallelism for a map of two entries. I further do not get the line “*TEST: true // Not correct, should be true*”

Comment: Is the scheduling relevant? Where do CollectionUtils come from? Are the xml files relevant? Why do we need the EventListeners? Why do you loop over collections containing only one element?

Comment: My mistake I forgot to replace a couple of things in my code.

It is done

Comment: I'd guess your MyRepository.findAll() isn't thread safe - it is a MockBean?